# How do I convert a 16-bit UCS-2 integer value into a char?

Tags: c#, unicode, text, character-encoding, ucs2

I am parsing values from a binary file. One value I am parsing is a 16-bit number which represents the UCS-2 encoding of a unicode character. I'm converting it to a character like this:

```
char c = (char)myInteger;
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as there are no byte-ordering issues this should be fine.